# How to replace country code to flag emoji in flutter

Tags: flutter

i have a list of countries with their sortname/countrycode in json format, which will be called in flutter. Is there a way i can convert all this code with their flag emojis?

For example: "sortname": "PL" will gives  (idk if you guys can see the flag or not)

```js
{
 "sortname": "PL",
 "name": "Poland",
}, {
 "sortname": "PT",
 "name": "Portugal",
}, {
 "sortname": "PR",
 "name": "Puerto Rico",
}, {
 "sortname": "QA",
 "name": "Qatar",
}, {
 "sortname": "RE",
 "name": "Reunion",
}, {
 "sortname": "RO",
 "name": "Romania",
}, {
 "sortname": "RU",
 "name": "Russia",
},
```

Answer (score 40):

Here's how I did it:

```dart
String countryCode = 'us';
String flag = countryCode.toUpperCase().replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'[A-Z]'),
     (match) => String.fromCharCode(match.group(0).codeUnitAt(0) + 127397));
print(flag);
```

1. `.toUpperCase()` Make all characters uppercase

   - us → US
2. `RegExp(r'[A-Z]')` Select each character with regex
3. `.replaceAllMapped()` Get each matched character

   - U
   - S
4. `.codeUnitAt(0)` Convert each character to a rune

   - 85
   - 83
5. `+ 127397` Convert each rune to a [regional indicator symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_indicator_symbol)

> 127397 = 127462 ('s HTML code) - 65 (A's rune value).

- 85 + 127397 = 127482
- 83 + 127397 = 127480

6. `.fromCharCode()` Convert the regional indicator symbols' values to a string (flag emoji)

   - →

Comment: Great, very helpful

Comment: working like a charm. But where is the 127387 coming from ?

Comment: @Chris The 127397 comes from the Regional Indicator Symbol [](https://unicode-table.com/en/1F1E6/)'s HTML code, **127462**, minus the rune value of A, **65**. 127462 - 65 = 127397. It's just mapping letters to their associated indicator symbols.

Comment: It gives output as country code letters converted to icon not flag emoji which may confuse lots of people.

Answer (score 3):

you could try [flutter_emoji package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_emoji#-readme-tab-)

Answer (score 0):

If this helps,

A thing you could do is store the Unicodes for the particular country in the **sortname** key. Then loop through it and decode the Unicode to an emoji string.

You can find the unicodes [here](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/iso3166)

Answer (score 0):

Working ways in 2022. Country flags icons can be used via these packages:

country_icons [package](https://pub.dev/packages/country_icons):

```
import 'package:country_icons/country_icons.dart';
Image.asset('icons/flags/svg/xx.svg', package: 'country_icons');
```

flag [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flag):

```
import 'package:flag/flag.dart'; 
Flag.fromCode(FlagsCode.AD, height: 100, width: null)
Flag.fromString('AD', height: null, width: null)
Flag.fromString('AD', height: 10, width: 100, fit: BoxFit.fill)
```

You can check country alpha2 codes and country names [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#:%7E:text=ISO%203166%2D1%20alpha%2D2%20codes%20are%20two%2Dletter,special%20areas%20of%20geographical%20interest.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```dart
extension CountryCode on String {
  String get flagEmoji => this
      .toUpperCase()
      .split('')
      .map((c) => c.codeUnitAt(0) + 127397)
      .map(String.fromCharCode)
      .join();
}
```